# Chamar uma função assíncrona em um ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asynctask

Como se faz a chamada de uma função assíncrona em um controlador não-assíncrono, para ser mais claro segue uma situação:

Tenho um form que ao salvar o mesmo precisa guardar dados no banco de dados e simultaneamente enviar um email notificando um usuário que foi feita tal ação no sistema. Porem quero que o envio de email seja executado assíncrono do método que grava os dados.

Eu utilizei como base um ex retirado da net, porem nele só mostra quando o método é chamado diretamente e não de quando ele é chamado de outro método não-assíncrono.

Código:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DuvidasForm form)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(form);

        var duvida = new Duvida 
        {
            nome_envio = form.nome_envio,
            email_envio = form.email_envio,
            assunto_envio = form.assunto_envio,
            msg_envio = form.msg_envio,
            data_envio = DateTime.Now,
            cursoid = form.cursoid,
            temaid = form.temaid,
            respondida = false
        };

        EnviarEmail(form.email_envio, form.assunto_envio, form.msg_envio);

        db.Duvida.Add(duvida);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return PartialView("_NotificacaoEmail");
    }

public async Task EnviarEmail(string toEmailAddress, string emailSubject, string emailMessage)
    {
        var smtp = new SmtpClient();


        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(toEmailAddress);

        message.Subject = emailSubject;
        message.Body = emailMessage;

        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mas existe alguma razão para a Action não ser assíncrona? E a sua questão é como realizar as tarefas paralelamente (cada uma em uma thread, para serem executadas "ao mesmo tempo") ou executar a tarefa como async, para não travar a Thread enquanto executa o envio?

Comment: @DiegoJeronymo Exatamente essa segunda opção. Pois quando o usuário clica no botão submit do formulário, ele da um delay, por causa que atualmente o envio de e-mail não esta assíncrono.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, deve ficar claro que a utilização de async/await em aplicações Asp.Net tem o propósito de apenas liberar as threads de requisições durante operações bloqueantes (I/O, requisições externas, consultas a bancos de dados, etc.) que o servidor dispõe para as suas aplicações.

O resultado disso é um melhor aproveitamento dos recursos do servidor, que se torna capaz de responder a mais requisições. Porém, isso não significa que as requisições serão mais rápidas ou que o usuário final sentirá alguma diferença durante a navegação diretamente por causa disso.

Esclarecidos esses pontos, a melhor maneira de chamar o seu método assíncrono é fazer a sua Action ser assíncrona também:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(DuvidasForm form)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(form);

    var duvida = new Duvida
    {
        nome_envio = form.nome_envio,
        email_envio = form.email_envio,
        assunto_envio = form.assunto_envio,
        msg_envio = form.msg_envio,
        data_envio = DateTime.Now,
        cursoid = form.cursoid,
        temaid = form.temaid,
        respondida = false
    };

    await EnviarEmail(form.email_envio, form.assunto_envio, form.msg_envio);

    db.Duvida.Add(duvida);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync(); // EF também pode ser executado async!

    return PartialView("_NotificacaoEmail");
}
```

Dessa forma, tanto o envio de e-mail quanto o SaveChanges() irão liberar a thread da requisição durante a sua execução. Com o uso do await em ambos, o fluxo de execução permanece semelhante ao de um método síncrono, porém com as vantagens que citei do async/await.

> Porem quero que o envio de email seja executado assíncrono do método que grava os dados.

Se a sua ideia é mandar ele fazer o envio sem esperar que ele de fato termine de enviar para executar a gravação no banco, então o seu método de envio de e-mails não deve usar as palavras-chave async/await:

```
public Task EnviarEmail(string toEmailAddress, string emailSubject, string emailMessage)
{
    var smtp = new SmtpClient();


    var message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(toEmailAddress);

    message.Subject = emailSubject;
    message.Body = emailMessage;

    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        return smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira, a aplicação vai passar direto pelo método, mandando enviar o e-mail, mas deixando através do retorno de **Task** a escolha para quem chamou ele de esperar ou não a sua execução.

A questão de como ficaria seu Controller depende de qual a sua intenção:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(DuvidasForm form)
{
    // o resto continua igual

    var taskEmail = EnviarEmail(form.email_envio, form.assunto_envio, form.msg_envio);

    db.Duvida.Add(duvida);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    // se você quer esperar explicitamente o fim do envio antes de retornar, então use a linha abaixo
    // await taskEmail;

    return PartialView("_NotificacaoEmail");
}
```

Comment: Não poderia ser mais claro! Sanou todas as duvidas que tinha de métodos async/await de uma forma pratica e clara! Obrg.